# ufw temporarily reject port on localhost for local testing

Tags: networking, localhost, telnet, ufw

I don't understand why those two commands don't block Port 8391 locally.

```bash
sudo ufw reject from 127.0.0.1 to 127.0.0.1 port 8391

telnet 127.0.0.1 8391
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
# [manual cancelling]
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

According to my understanding, the first command should block all network traffic for port 8391 for connections with either one of the endpoints on localhost and the second command should fail as it starts a telnet session from localhost to localhost on port 8391.
However, the telnet on 8391 (NOT 23) makes a successful connection.

I have some code which makes a connection on port 8391 and I want to see if it gracefully fails when the port is blocked (normally this should not be the case, but I want to the test this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is discussed in the post
[Deny from localhost with ufw](https://serverfault.com/questions/473348/deny-from-localhost-with-ufw?_gl=1*9tx4z3*_ga*OTU2OTY1MzE2LjE1MTg0NDc4OTE.*_ga_S812YQPLT2*MTcxMDk0MDE5Ni41MDQuMC4xNzEwOTQwMTk2LjAuMC4w).

The non-accepted answer by Lucky.V seems to better address the problem:

> According what I tried it is not possible using ufw.
>
> The ufw stores user defined rules into separate iptables chain
> (*ufw-user-input* for INPUT chain and so on).
>
> Unfortunately if you check the INPUT chain, the *ufw-user-input*
> subchain is the last one. The first one is called *ufw-before-input*
> and contains the rule that accepts all the localhost communication.
> Thanks to this the iptables never get to your localhost rule that if
> defined in *ufw-user-input*.
>
> **At the end I disabled the localhost communication by inserting that rule as a first rule in INPUT chain directly. This can be done by
> something like:**
>
> ```
> sudo iptables  -I INPUT -p tcp -i lo --dport 5702 -j DROP
> ```
>
> This will drop all the packets that goes into TCP port 5702 on
> localhost.
>
> If you want to check all the chains in iptables, use:
>
> ```
> sudo iptables -nvL
> ```

You need to directly use iptables, rather than ufw.

Comment: OK, that worked. Would it be possible if you complete your answer with the command to reset the rule, please?

Comment: Reset which rule?

Comment: `sudo iptables  -I INPUT -p tcp -i lo --dport 5702 -j DROP`

Comment: Do you mean like [this](https://kerneltalks.com/virtualization/how-to-reset-iptables-to-default-settings/) ?

Comment: In the meantime I found it out. I just need to replace the `-I` with `-D`, then the rule is removed again.